# How to interpret the output of supervised discretization in Weka?

Tags: weka

The dataset is the `weather.numeric.arff`.

Where are the intervals from discretization? Why 'all'?

[image: I]

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not know why you get this result. I tried other settings with the supervised Discretize filter with the same outcome.
2. I thought it would perhaps be because the data set is small, but I triplicated it (so there's 42 instances, not 14), and the same thing happened.
3. BUT, if I use the unsupervised Discrete filter, it works.

That line is:

```
Discretize -B 10 -M -1.0 -R first-last
```

This gives 4 intervals for the 14 cases.

Comment: Researching I found that WEKA puts all in one bin because Fayyad and Irani criterion. Thank you for help!